# Looking for layer names for keras inceptionresnetv2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Really don't have much idea of what I'm doing, followed this tutorial to process deepdream images https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wkh72OKmcKI

Trying to change the base model data set to any from here, https://keras.io/api/applications/#models-for-image-classification-with-weights-trained-on-imagenet particularly InceptionResNetV2 currently. InceptionV3 uses "mixed0" up to "mixed10" whereas, the former data set uses a different naming system apparently.

Would have to change this section

```
# Maximize the activations of these layers
names = ['mixed3', 'mixed5']
layers = [base_model.get_layer(name).output for name in names]

# Create the feature extraction model
dream_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=layers)
```

I'm getting an error "no such layer: mixed3"

So yea, just trying to figure out how to get the names for the layers in this data set as well as others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply enter the following code to find out the model architecture(including layer names).

```
#Model denotes the Inception model
model.summary()
```

Or to visualize complex relationships,

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, but where do I enter that? In powershell, or that notebook?

Comment: @user14665806 Obviously on the notebook.

Comment: turned out to be base-model.summary()

Comment: @user14665806 Please mark your question as answered.